# Accept own answer causes "you reached the reputation cap"

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-card

I asked a question and answered it myself. This caused a single entry in the profile popup with a value of zero. If I point at the zero, it explains "you reached the reputation cap with this question." However, I did not reach the cap; it is zero because points aren't awarded for accepting or being accepted by yourself.

Looks like there's a false assumption in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be properly handled in the next build, you'll get a proper "Self-accepted answer" tooltip on that 0.